# How to remove python3.7.2 from /usr/local/bin

Tags: python3

I have accidentally installed python3.7 in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin/.

This makes scipy not available for some of my scripts.

Is there a way to uninstall python3.7 and reinstall in /usr/bin/

Thanks!
SP

Comment: How did you install python? Have you tried using a package manager like homebrew? If you don't want to go the package manager route you should be able to just move the file. Check the version by entering into terminal python --version and the location by which python

Comment: How did you install it? Have you looked up how to remove Python and followed any instructions? What have you tried?